# Find index of consecutive values in a list, if from negative values goes to positive using Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, python-itertools

I have a python List like this:

`List = [-550, -455, -355, -215, -195, 500, 645, 800, 975]`

I want to check two consecutive values in List, if value from *negative* goes to *positive* and print *the index* of those values as below:

**result:**

`index=[4,5]`

Comment: WIll there only be one such index? In other words, is the data sorted?

Comment: Then `next([i-1, i] for i, n in enumerate(List) if n >= 0)` will do.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple, no-brainer loop.

```
for i in range(0, len(List)-1):
    if List[i] < 0 and List[i + 1] > 0:
        print(i, i + 1)
```

As you are a new contributor, some advice: consider practicing on writing basic loops with more than one loop invariants.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the list with itself at an offset of one like:

```
zip(l, l[1:])
```

This will create pairs like:

```
[(-550, -455)...]
```

If you [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) that to get the indices, you can then filter for the cases where the first element is negative and the second is positive:

```
l = [-550.0, -455.0, -355.0, -215.0, -195.0, 500.0, 645.0, 800.0, 975.0, 1265.0, 1370.0, 1615.0, 1615.0, 1615.0, 1615.0]

[[idx, idx+1] for idx, [a, b] in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])) if a < 0 < b]
# evaluates to [[4, 5]]
```

Comment: I did a naive catch to what you pointed out, I may think a better way to implement this, my point is only to demonstrate the itertools module which is very powerful

Comment: It's a nice answer @FedericoBaù, and it never hurts to point point out how useful itertools is.

Answer (score 1):

One cool solution is to use the **Standard Library Itertools!**

### 1. [filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

```py
from itertools import filterfalse

list = [-550, -455, -355, -215, -195, 500, 645, 800, 975]

def get_pos_neg(lst):

    result = filterfalse(lambda x: x<0 , lst)
    positive_value = list.index(next(result))
    neg = list[positive_value-1]
    negative_value = list.index(neg)
    return [negative_value, positive_value]

print(get_pos_neg(list))  # [4, 5]
```

---

### 2.[takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) & [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

> EDIT:  As @ Mark Meyer pointed out, `takewhile` and `dropwhile` won' run if the condition is met, hence I modified with a check first. Is only for demonstration purposes to how to get advantage of the itertools module, probably there are more efficient way to achieve this.

```py
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

list = [-550, -455, -355, -215, -195, 500, 645, 800, 975]
list_pos = [-195, 500, 645, 800, 975, -550, -455, -355, -215]
def get_pos_neg(lst):

    if lst[0] < 0:
        negative = [n for n in takewhile(lambda x:  x<0, lst)]
        positive = [n for n in dropwhile(lambda x: x<0, lst)]
        polar_change = [list.index(negative[-1]), list.index(positive[0])]
        return polar_change
    else:
        negative = [n for n in takewhile(lambda x: x > 0, lst)]
        positive = [n for n in dropwhile(lambda x: x > 0, lst)]
        polar_change = [list.index(negative[-1]), list.index(positive[0])]
        return polar_change


start_neg = get_pos_neg(list)
star_pos = get_pos_neg(list_pos)
print(start_neg)  # [4, 5]
print(star_pos)   # [4, 5]
```